# Jenkins build outside of workspace

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins/Hudson and am trying to migrate a C make-based project from buildbot. For legacy reasons, the build system is hard-coded to build outside of the versioned source tree (git), one directory above, in a separate directory. E.g.:

```
workspace
  .git
  foo
  bar
build
  artifacts
```

Besides the fact that it ends up creating a directory outside the workspace, Jenkins won't recognize items in the build/ directory above to archive as artifacts.

How can I make this kind of build system work with Hudson? Building in-source-tree is not a short-term option. The only option I found was "use custom workspace," but all this does it hard-code the workspace directory to some other directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer my own question: there is indeed an option in Jenkins git plugin to check out to a local subdirectory instead of the root of the workspace. With the git plugin, click on the Advanced button and fill in the field "Local subdirectory for repo (optional)".

Comment: This now appears to have moved to the "Additional Behaviours" section

Comment: Just FYI, this does not work with the pipeline multibranch plugin as it can't find the jenkinsfile

Answer (score 3):

I don't find the option that *djs* mentioned, but you can specify a different work directory:

1. Configure job
2. Extended Project settings
3. Use custom work space

This can be set to everywhere you want, also the workspace of a different job.

Comment: Beware, the artifact step won't work with paths outside the workspace. The workaround is to copy the artifacts back into the workspace, or make a symbolic link to their directory.