# Jenkins git clone into a subdir of workspace

Tags: git, continuous-integration, jenkins

I want to follow the [Jenkins PHP template](http://jenkins-php.org/) as much as possible, but I've ran into problems in using it with the git. The template expects everything to be cloned into a `src` directory of the main workspace directory, but there doesn't seem to be an option to do this with the git plugin in jenkins?

There is this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026079/jenkins-build-outside-of-workspace/7091901#7091901) but I don't seem to have the option under the git advanced options to choose a directory.

When choosing SVN there is a clear `Local module directory` which does what I want but it doesn't exist for the git plugin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an option "Local subdirectory for repo (optional)" under the advanced options that should do exactly what you want.

Comment: What advanced options? I don't see this under either git advanced options or project advanced options.

Comment: Hmm, looks like there's two "advanced options" buttons -- one under the repo URL and one just above "repository browser". When I click the latter, I get about a dozen new options including the one I mentioned.

Comment: Many thanks, it was under the second advanced section. Durrrr