# Clone git repo outside jenkins workspace

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm Using Git plugin `2.0.3`.
I want to clone my git repository somewhere outside jenkins workspace.

Ex: Assume  my jenkins workspace is `C:\UserData\jenkins` and I want to clone My git repo in `C:\sumit` directory.

Form [Jenkins build outside of workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026079/jenkins-build-outside-of-workspace):
It says to use **Local subdirectory for repo (optional)** option but as you can see for this version there is no such option available.

Even i tried to use `check out to a sub-directory` option by using relative path but that is also not working.

[image]

**So Is there any way to solve this problem..?**

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want checkout your git repository outside of your  jenkins workspace, you need to install git on your machine and add git to class path then type your commend for checkout.